# Dynamically Pivot a SQL data table with summary

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dynamic-pivot

I have the following data table which is generated from a process of reading a barcode and packing some garments accordingly, what I'm trying to do is to pivot this table to have the summary of this packing process.

My source table:

[image: Table]

And the result which I'm trying to reach is like:

[image: Result]

I tried to do it with the following code but I'm having problems with the result which is returning only one size and all the colors.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TBL_TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##TBL_TEMP

-- This parameter will hold the dynamically created SQL script
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--This parameter will hold the Pivoted Column values
DECLARE @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @PivotColumns = (SELECT DISTINCT [Size])
FROM [dbo].[Tabel]

--Create the dynamic query with all the values for
--pivot column at runtime
--LIST ALL FILEDS EXCEPT PIVOT COLUMN

SET @SQLQuery =
   N'SELECT [ColorName]' +   @PivotColumns + '
   INTO ##TBL_TEMP
   FROM [dbo].[Tabel]

   PIVOT( MAX([Qty])
      FOR [Size] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS Q'

--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

/* VIEW PIVOTED TABLE RESULTS */
Select * from ##TBL_TEMP
```

Could you please kindly help me to have the result using C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing small things in your query. Try these small changes in your pivot columns and the Select statement of your dynamic query.

Just add the BoxNo and StyleCode in your dynamic SQL select query and PIVOT the data for SUM[Qty]

```
 SET   @SQLQuery =
 N'SELECT [BoxNo],[StyleCode],[ColorName],' +   @PivotColumns + '
 INTO ##TBL_TEMP
 FROM [dbo].[Tabel]

 PIVOT(SUM([Qty]) 
   FOR [Size] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS Q'

 --Execute dynamic query
 EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

 --VIEW PIVOTED TABLE RESULTS--
 SELECT * FROM  ##TBL_TEMP
```

Please see the screenshot of my sample data

[image]

Try this piece of code now :

```
Select BoxNo,StyleCode,ColorName,Size,Qty 
INTO #tbl_1 
FROM [dbo].[1202-904200]

DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE  @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @PivotColumns= ISNULL(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME([Size]) FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT [Size] FROM #tbl_1) as Size 

--Create the dynamic query with all the values for pivot column at runtime.
SET @SQLQuery =  N'SELECT [BoxNo],[StyleCode],[ColorName],' + @PivotColumns + '
                 INTO ##TBL_TEMP
                 FROM #tbl_1 -- Replace your source here to #tbl_1
                 PIVOT(SUM([Qty]) 
                 FOR [Size] IN (' + @PivotColumns + ')) AS Q'

--Execute dynamic query
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery

/* VIEW PIVOTED TABLE RESULTS */
SELECT * FROM  ##TBL_TEMP
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked after making the changes as you suggested, but I miss the **BoxNo** and the **StyleCode** columns from the output. Also, it returned the rows without sum. can you help me to do so?

Comment: Please check my edited answer now. It should help you.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped so much, still, I couldn't get the sums of the *Sizes* related to every *BoxNo*, I have them in separated rows now, but I'll try to figure something out with the output table, thanks again.

Comment: Can you please post your query and the output as it should be able to give you what you expect.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my query code, maybe I did something wrong?
"[dbo].[1202-904200]" is my source table which I'm trying to pivot.

Comment: Interesting. I can't really say until I look your data in source table in detail. Can you try putting only the required columns BoxNo,StyleCode,ColorName,Size,Qty from your source table into a temp table. And then use the temp table as source in the dynamic sql.

Comment: To be frank, I'm not that expert in SqlServer :( can you please teach me how to do it by editing the code? I added a snapshot of my source datatable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check my edited answer and try that code. Hope it helps.

Comment: IT WORKED!! I don't know how to thank you, really really thank you man, I hope you find solutions to all of your problems.